# OpenOffice.org Outline Numbering Default

Tags: formatting, openoffice, word-processing

In OpenOffice.org, the default option under Tools->Outline Numbering->Paragraph Style is listed as "Heading 1". I want it to be "Block Title #1" for cross compatibility with Microsoft Word. There is a template that I must use from there. I've managed to reengineer the entire template other than this bit. When you open their template, it sets Block Title #1 as the highest ordered item so that it shows up in the Document Map.

When you change the item listed above to Block Title #1 in OO.o it shows up in the navigator, but going through those steps every time is time consuming and inefficient.

Is there any way to do this (every time I open a document with this template, the default heading will be Block Title #1 rather than Heading 1 without me having to change it) without recompiling it from source or something insanely complicated?

If it matters, I'm running 64-bit Linux Mint 7 with OpenOffice.org version 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general answer but worth a try.

If you save the template as you want it to be and with the right selections done, and then open it again does the application not store those values as they were saved?